# Foreign Key problem when migrating migrations in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, mysqli, migration

Am working on a Laravel 5.6 application whereby I have 2 tables mainly `sponsors` table and `children` table. Am creating a one to many relationship between the tables before migrating them. A child may have many sponsors.
 The problem is I get this error when migrating them using `php artisan migrate` command:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1005 Can't create table `larangular`.`#sql-520c_21f` (errno: 150
>   "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table
>   `sponsors` add constraint `sponsors_child_id_foreign` foreign key
>   (`child_id`) references `children` (`id`) on delete cascade)

**Sponsors migration**

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('sponsors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('child_id')->unsignedInteger();
        $table->foreign('child_id')->references('id')->on('children')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('child_id')->references('id')->on('children');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('nationality');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Children migration**

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('children', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('age');
        $table->string('gender');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your children migration runs before your sponsors migration, and then the column should be this:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('child_id');

// or 

$table->integer('child_id')->unsigned();
```

Answer (score 1):

[`unsignedInteger`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_unsignedInteger) is a function that creates a column, you should not call it on an existing column.

```
// This creates an unsigned integer column.
$table->unsignedInteger('child_id');
```